# Not outputting the right Mean or Variance

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, while-loop

My assignment is to take numbers, one per line and calculate the mean and median and variance and Standard Deviation. The while loop stops when null is entered or 500 numbers have been entered. I calculated the median and Standard Deviation but for some reason my output for the variance and mean are wrong. Also if you could help me with my parameters for while loop to also end when 500 numbers are entered.

My input:

> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 17.0, 18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 22.0, 22.0, 22.0, 22.0, 22.0, 22.0, 22.0, 23.0, 23.0, 23.0, 23.0, 23.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0, 26.0, 26.0, 26.0, 26.0, 26.0, 26.0, 26.0, 26.0, 27.0, 27.0, 27.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 29.0, 29.0, 29.0, 29.0, 29.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 31.0, 31.0, 31.0, 31.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 34.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 36.0, 36.0, 36.0, 37.0, 37.0, 37.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 38.0, 39.0, 39.0, 39.0, 39.0, 39.0, 39.0, 39.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 41.0, 42.0, 42.0, 42.0, 42.0, 43.0, 43.0, 43.0, 43.0, 44.0, 44.0, 44.0, 45.0, 45.0, 45.0, 45.0, 45.0, 46.0, 46.0, 46.0, 46.0, 46.0, 46.0, 47.0, 47.0, 47.0, 47.0, 47.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 49.0, 50.0, 50.0, 51.0, 51.0, 51.0, 51.0, 51.0, 52.0, 52.0, 52.0, 52.0, 52.0, 53.0, 53.0, 53.0, 53.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 56.0, 57.0, 57.0, 58.0, 58.0, 58.0, 58.0, 58.0, 59.0, 59.0, 59.0, 59.0, 59.0, 59.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 62.0, 62.0, 62.0, 62.0, 63.0, 63.0, 63.0, 64.0, 64.0, 64.0, 64.0, 64.0, 64.0, 64.0, 64.0, 65.0, 65.0, 65.0, 65.0, 65.0, 65.0, 66.0, 66.0, 66.0, 66.0, 66.0, 66.0, 67.0, 67.0, 67.0, 68.0, 68.0, 68.0, 68.0, 68.0, 68.0, 68.0, 68.0, 68.0, 69.0, 69.0, 69.0, 69.0, 69.0, 69.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 71.0, 71.0, 71.0, 71.0, 71.0, 71.0, 71.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 73.0, 73.0, 73.0, 73.0, 74.0, 74.0, 75.0, 75.0, 75.0, 75.0, 76.0, 76.0, 76.0, 76.0, 76.0, 77.0, 77.0, 77.0, 77.0, 77.0, 77.0, 77.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 79.0, 79.0, 79.0, 79.0, 79.0, 79.0, 79.0, 79.0, 79.0, 80.0, 80.0, 80.0, 80.0, 81.0, 81.0, 81.0, 82.0, 82.0, 82.0, 82.0, 82.0, 82.0, 83.0, 83.0, 83.0, 83.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0, 84.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 86.0, 86.0, 87.0, 87.0, 87.0, 87.0, 87.0, 87.0, 88.0, 88.0, 88.0, 88.0, 88.0, 89.0, 89.0, 89.0, 89.0, 90.0, 90.0, 90.0, 91.0, 91.0, 91.0, 91.0, 92.0, 92.0, 92.0, 93.0, 93.0, 93.0, 93.0, 94.0, 94.0, 94.0, 94.0, 94.0, 95.0, 95.0, 95.0, 96.0, 96.0, 96.0, 96.0, 96.0, 97.0, 97.0, 97.0, 98.0, 98.0, 98.0, 98.0, 99.0, 99.0, 99.0, 100.0, 100.0

null

My output:

> Mean: 47.21
>   Median: 47.00
>   Variance: 857.34
>   Standard Deviation: 29.28

Expected Output:

> Mean: 47.27
>   Variance: 856.71
>   Standard Deviation: 29.27

```
BufferedReader stdin =
                    new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat ("0.00");
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits (2);//Sets Min digits
            nf.setMaximumFractionDigits (2);//Sets Max digits
            String inputValue;
            double sum = 0;
            double counter = 0;
            double median = 0;
            double variance = 0;
            double varianceCounter = 0;






            List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();


            while((inputValue = stdin.readLine()) != null && !inputValue.equals("")){
                input.add(inputValue);
                numbers.add (Double.parseDouble(inputValue));        
            }
                 for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
                    sum += (numbers.get(i));
                    counter++;  
                }

            Collections.sort(numbers);
            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
            if  (numbers.size() % 2 == 0){
                median = (numbers.get(numbers.size()/2-1) + numbers.get(numbers.size()/2))/2;
            }
            else {
                median = (numbers.get((numbers.size())/2));
            }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
                    variance += numbers.get(i) * numbers.get(i);
                    varianceCounter++;
            }






            System.out.println ("Mean: " + (nf.format(sum/counter)));
            System.out.println ("Median: " + (nf.format(median)));
            System.out.println ("Variance: " + (nf.format((variance/varianceCounter)-(sum*sum)/(varianceCounter*varianceCounter))));    
    System.out.println ("Standard Deviation: " + (nf.format(Math.sqrt((variance/varianceCounter)-(sum*sum)/(varianceCounter*varianceCounter)))));           
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where using the formatter in your IDE (if not your debugger) helps.

The problem you have is you are summing all the values on every input.

```
while ((inputValue = stdin.readLine()) != null && !inputValue.equals("")){
    input.add(inputValue);
    numbers.add (Double.parseDouble(inputValue));        
    // sum all the values on every input i.e. 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
        sum += (numbers.get(i));
        counter++;  
    }
```

What you should be doing is reading all the input and only then summing all the values.

```
while ((inputValue = stdin.readLine()) != null && !inputValue.equals("")){
    input.add(inputValue);
    numbers.add (Double.parseDouble(inputValue));        
}
// sum all the values AFTER all the input. i.e. 1 2 3 4
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){
    sum += (numbers.get(i));
    counter++;  
}
```

BTW The counter should always be the `input.size()`

Comment: So close the while loop before the for loops?

Comment: @swaguire correct. One loop for each stage in the processing. You don't need nested loops here.  BTW except for the median, you can calculate the mean and variance without storing the values.

Comment: Thank you so much! Also do you know what my parameter should be for my while loop to make it also end when 500 numbers have been entered?

Comment: @swaguire the variance is the sum of square of the *difference* with the mean, not the sum of squares (unless the mean is 0)

Comment: Just for future references how would I do it differently without storing them?

Comment: @swaguire the number of inputs doesn't change this code, (unless you have a few billion)  you can calculate the sum and count as you go without storing the values, the variance is trickier and I always have to look that up ;)

Comment: I know the number of outputs doesn't change the code I just need to know how to write the parameter to make the while loop stop when 500 numbers have been entered would this work  input.size()<=500

Comment: @swaguire yes, but that's not a great idea, what if the input is not exactly 500? Your program can handle any size, including 500 now.

Comment: I'm still having difficulty calculating the variance

Comment: @swaguire most likely you are doing something wrong. Did you do what I suggested?

Comment: Yes well I passed all my tests for my assignment besides one and I dont understand why this one out put isn't working look at my edited questions it will show the input and output

Comment: @swaguire I can't image what you are doing wrong from your output alone. Can you add an edit with your nicely formatted new code?

Comment: I just did thank you for all your help so far and patience